# Spring boot taskscheduler

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

I have a web server created with spring boot. I need to run tasks once in a while (for example once in a 5 minute).

```
taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RunnableTask(),new Date(), 5000);
```

My question is, will it work when the station goes to sleep?
I got some system log which says:

> HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=1h54s165ms).

And RunnableTask didn't start during a time when the station was in a sleep mode.
What I have to do to make the RunnableTask works even if the station in a sleep mode.
In general, can a server machine go to sleep?